# Armazenar conteúdo / variáveis no Model — PHP MVC

Tags: php, mvc, viewmodel

Olá,

Estou começando a estudar o padrão MVC para PHP. Já li diversas perguntas aqui no StackOverflow, já estudei a documentação do Laravel e li diversos artigos.

Escolhi o conceito abordado neste post como base - https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

A partir disto surgiu uma primeira dúvida:

Estou criando um site simples, inicialmente sem banco de dados. Tenho apenas algumas variáveis para cada página ($title, $tags, $description, etc), um array com valores e o foreach. **Eu devo armazenar todas estas variáveis no Model das minhas páginas? (Ex. HomeModel, SobreModel, etc) e passar diretamente para o view?**

O diagrama abaixo confere?

[image: Diagrama]

Faço esta pergunta, pois tenho visto em diversos tutoriais as variáveis sendo armazenadas no Controller, assim como os Views sendo acionados no Controller. E o Model sendo utilizado basicamente para questões de acesso e solicitação a Banco de Dados.

Obrigado!

---

**UPDATE:**

Beleza, acho que entendi. Vou dar uma olhada na pergunta que você enviou também. Obrigado!

Só pra ilustrar como estou fazendo no momento:

---

**Tenho em minha rota:**

```
$route->get( '/', 'HomeController@index' );
```

---

**Em HomeController tenho isto:**

```
class HomeController {

        public function index() {

            $model = new HomeModel;
            return view( 'home', $model );

        }

}
```

---

**E finalmente em HomeModel tenho:**

```
class HomeModel {

    public $title;
    public $description;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->title = 'Título do meu site';
        $this->description = 'Descrição do meu site';

    }

}
```

Comment: na boa MVC é otimo mas prefiro me organizar por MVP ( model,view,present) a unica diferenã he que no mvp o view ou no caso o present nao acessa o model diretamente, assim fica bem mais organizado. eu armazenaria as variáveis no controler por esta é a função dele.

Comment: Não se se vai ajudar ou complicar, mas dê uma olhada no conceito `ViewModel` do `ASP.Net MVC`.

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada nestes conceitos.

Comment: Deixa eu tentar algo simples. O usuário acessa a *home* e nela há um link para cadastro - por exemplo - *www.domain.com/cadastro.html*. Seu `core` vai carregar o *controller\cadastro*, ele vai receber o `input`, mandar pro `model` que vai retornar o status da operação. Dependendo do resultado, o `controller` invoca a `view` correspondente, *www.domain.com/cadastro-sucesso.html* ou *www.domain.com/cadastro.html* onde serão exibidos os erros.

Comment: Quase isso... `title` e `description` fazem parte da *view*, não compõem o modelo. Nesse caso essas variáveis cairiam melhor em um arquivo tipo *config*, mas para fins de **TESTE**, use como variável global e cheme-as na sua *view*. Um exemplo mais usual seria seu modelo retornar um array qualquer e você usar um loop na *view* para iterar os elementos

Comment: Até havia feito desta maneira inicialmente, utilizando define.

Mas como tenho um título ($title) e uma descrição ($description) para cada página. (Home, Sobre, Produtos, Contato), fiz desta maneira. Isto é, armazenei no Model de cada página.

O meu view, é uma função que carrega o html que esta na pasta view, e o segundo parâmetro são estas variáveis que peguei no model. No meu arquivo html tenho os escapes.

Answer (score -1):

Recomendo que utilize estas variáveis nos controladores porque o uso de modelos só é necessário quando for utilizar o banco de dados, o ideal é que estas informações estivessem em banco, mas como ainda não, definitivamente no controlador. Uma view não pode acessar o modelo, sempre tem que existem a ponte que é o controller.

Comment: em MVC a view pode acessar o Model por isso comentei sobre MVP

Comment: Não é o que aquele diagrama indica, e também seria uma prática deplorável misturar a cama de interface com a de dados.

Comment: O `model` nada tem a ver com (só) banco de dados, é a camada onde se trabalha as *regras de negócio* - manipulação, validação, etc...

Comment: Então este diagrama não esta correto?

Comment: Eu diria pra esquecer qualquer diagrama e focar em cada camada e sua responsabilidade. Compreendendo isso você consegue identificar o funcionamento de *qualquer* diagrama sobre `MVC`, certos ou equivocados.